# Cortana Channel Integration to Bot takes to browser after invocation

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-invoke

I created basic Web app bot (LUIS template, SDK v3) using Azure Bot service. I added some intents and entities and have tested that bot works in web chat control.

After that I added Cortana Channel to it. Gave Invocation name as "my desk" and deployed to Cortana.

I made sure my i am logged into Cortana using same MS account as i used to register into bot framework and language and region settings are En-US on my PC as well as Cortana.

I invoke by asking "Hey Cortana, ask my desk get green book". After this, it opens a browser with some search results.

I am unable to understand whats the problem here? How to debug this issue , in which direction? This is a very simple basic bot that Cortana i think is not able to invoke.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Please forward along your Windows version and build. There are a few reasons why this could happen, including 1/ is your MSA logged in with Cortana (see the notebook) the same as that under which you deployed to the Cortana Channel, 2/ have you installed anything that redirects bing search? if you type "ask my desk get green book" different from using the mic?

Comment: Also, does the bot work in webchat? And have you tried using CURL to hit your endpoint directly?  (ie curl -X POST https://myskill.azureservices.net/api/messages or whatever)

Comment: Can you invoke any other skills, like Xbox or Akinator?

Comment: Thanks Micromuncher... Answers as follows:  1) Win version: Win 10 Pro version: 1709 OS build: 16299.726    2) I dont think i explicitly installed anything that redirects to bing. But, what could be that one so that i can check if its installed? Bot works in web chat and does reply to me with expected message from code. 3) I made sure my MSA accounts are same at both places.  4) No i havnt tried CURL etc yet 5) Yes i can invoke xbox

Comment: i am behind this issue for 2 days... not able to understand whats the problem here :(

Comment: I tried curl to invoke my bot endpoint as                                                           
curl https://thisismybot1.azurewebsites.net/api/messages. this gives me response as : "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

Comment: Also, post request                                                                                             curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"message": "get red book"}'  https://thisismybot1.azurewebsites.net/api/messages            results in error "BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!"

Comment: POST is right, and the error is right (because you'd need to send in the App id and key.) Send an email to skillsup at microsoft dot com with the bot name, invocation name, and other details.  You could try deploy to group and re-add your email address after clicking the join group URL.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with cookies; even when changing the user. Please confirm that you have changed between MSAs, or specifically, an MSA and AAD account during your development process.  If you do change between accounts on the Cortana notebook, you can try clearing Edge (used by Cortana to render) cookies or Cortana data here.  https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-microsoft-edge-and-privacy

Please let me know.